# Difficulty with my self built histogram in MatLab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am trying to implement a simple function that its the same with the default hist() by MatLab.

We have two same images with different brightness and we have to convert them to grayscale and then use the default function of MatLab `hist()`  to get the histograms (so far so good!).

Then we have to implement the function hist `my_hist()` , and when i am trying to count the frequency of the intensity the results are not the same.

It seems that it sums-up the frequency of 254 & 255 to 254 and 255 is zero!I dont know what the problem is, any help would be appreciated.

here is the code for the command line:

```
%Read the images and convert them from rgb to grayscale
i=imread('pic1.jpg');
j=rgb2gray(i);
x=imread('pic2.jpg');
y=rgb2gray(x);

%Display the two images
figure
imshow(j)
figure 
imshow(y)

%Display the histogram of the two images
[a,b] = hist(j(:),0:1:255);
figure 
plot(b,a)
[c,d]=hist(y(:),0:1:255);
figure 
plot(d,c)

%Call of the built-in function
my_hist('pic1.jpg','pic2.jpg')
```

And here is the code of the self built function:

```
function  []= my_hist( x,y)

%Read the images and convert them from rgb to grayscale
pic1=imread(x);
i=rgb2gray(pic1);
pic2=imread(y);
j=rgb2gray(pic2);

%Initialize two vectors to be the axis for histogram
plotx=0:255;
ploty=zeros(1,256);

%Take the dimensions of the first image pic1
[m,n] = size(i);

%With 2 loops we go through the matrix of the image and count how many
%pixels have the same intensity

for k=1:m 
   for l=1:n
num=i(k,l)+1;
      ploty(num)=ploty(num)+1;
   end
 end

%Display the histogram for the first image pic1
figure
plot(plotx,ploty);

%Initialize two vectors to be the axis for histogram
plotx2=0:255;
ploty2=zeros(1,256);

%Take the dimensions of the second image pic2
[m2,n2] = size(j);

%With 2 loops we go through the matrix of the image and count how many
%pixels have the same intensity
for o=1:m2 
 for p=1:n2
num2=j(o,p)+1;
    ploty2(num2)=ploty2(num2)+1;
 end
end

%Display the histogram for the second image pic2
figure
plot(plotx2,ploty2);
end
```

And here are the images [pic1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbc5vg9ydjpgvy3/pic1.jpg) and [pic2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmw2z4ox5rhhwjj/pic2.jpg?m).

Comment: I updated the terminology a bit. In Matlab a builtin function is actually a function that is built into the software by Mathworks (rather than by yourself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem due to your image being of integer type `uint8` which can only range from 0-255:

```
>> a= uint8(255)

a =

  255

>> a=a+1

a =

  255
```

Convert your data to say type `uint16` with

```
j = uint16(j);
y = uint16(y);
```

and your problem should be gone:

```
>> a=uint16(a)

a =

    255

>> a=a+1

a =

    256
```

Comment: i want the range to be 0-255 but the problem has been fixed.. i just found the min & max intensity and created the two vectors according to them and the histogram has been created just fine...But thanks any way Try Hard